# Android CSS3 support, webview and rendering engine

Tags: android, css, webview, webkit, opera

I am using a WebView inside an android app, and I have problems with CSS3 support for earlier android versions.

I am using this css class as an example (which should display a green circle):

```
.board {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  background: green;

}
```

If running in android 4.2 it works fine, but in Android 2.2 I don't get the circle but instead a square (as expected if there's no CSS3 support).

If I launch the Opera browser in Android 2.2 it works fine, but I need it to run my html inside a WebView.

So, the questions are :

- is there anyway to embed the Opera engine inside my WebView, or is
  there any view exported by Opera I can use in my app?
- do I need to limit the availability of my app to android 3.x or android 4.x?
- what other choices do I have?

Thanks.